# Set environment variable as different user when program itself run as root

Tags: c++, linux

I want to set environment variable as user 'abc' and my program runs as root. I have tried with 'seteuid' but it affects the whole application's threads which is running as root. When I provide `su abc -c ' env ENV1=value1 pwd`, it will expose the environment variable in "ps" command which leaks the security. Below is the sample code which is working as user 'abc' but not able to set envrironment variable with user 'abc'.

```
std::wstring ExecuteCommand(const std::wstring &command, int &error_code)
{
    std::wstring res;
    std::string s_cmd(command.begin(), command.end());
    FILE *fPtr = popen((const char *)s_cmd.c_str(), "r");

    if (fPtr)
    {
            char buffer[1024];
            int cnt;

            while ((cnt = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fPtr)) > 0)
            {
                    buffer[cnt] = 0;
                    std::string s_val = std::string(buffer);
                    std::wstring wsTmp(s_val.begin(), s_val.end());
                    res += wsTmp;
            }            

            error_code = pclose(fPtr);            

            return res;
    }

    return L"";
}


int main()
{    
    std::wstring command = L"su abc -c 'ls -ltr /home/abc'";
    int error_code = -1;
    ExecuteCommand(command, error_code);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried with setenv & seteoid but seems it affect other threads as well so Can you suggest how to set environment variable as user 'abc' when application is running as root ?

Comment: Please pay close attention to the tags you select. The code you show isn't C, it's C++. I fixed the tag for you this time.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "as user". Environment variables are per process, not per user.

Comment: Yes right. It will be per process but here we are using "popen" which in turns create different process so i want to pass environment variable along with popen which will be executed by abc user.

Comment: I think you need `fork`, `execve`, and `setuid`.

Comment: At this point I think you need to do it manually, not go through `popen`.